# Strip tags in PHP with an allowed list but remove all attributes

Tags: php, strip-tags

In PHP, what is the fastest and simplest way to strip all HTML tags from a string, except the ones in an allowed list but by removing all HTML attributes.

The built-in function `strip_tags` would have done the job but the attributes are kept for the tags in the allowed list.
I don't know if using regular expressions is the best way and I also don't know if parsing the string wouldn't be greedy.

Comment: A very hacky but simple solution would be to replace the tags you want to keep with a replacement character or string, then call `strip_tags`. Afterwards replace the allowed tags back. But for security reasons I would not use `strip_tags` in the first place, unless the input is already otherwise validated.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really figure out the solution you suggested. Wouldn't it be the same as if I simply used `strip_tags` with allowed tags? Also, can you please explain why you wouldn't use `strip_tags` for security reason?

Comment: WordPress code has a battle-tested html cleaner, FWIW. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/

Comment: This question is missing its [mcve] and a coding attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression might fail if an attribute has a `>` as a value of an attribute.

A safer way would be to use `DomDocumment` but note that the input should be valid HTML and also the output might possibly be standardized.

```php
<?php

$htmlString = '<span>777</span><div class="hello">hello <b id="12">world</b></div>';
$stripped = strip_tags($htmlString, '<div><b>');

$dom = new DOMDocument;              // init new DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($stripped);           // load the HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
}

$cleanHtmlString = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->firstChild->childNodes as $node) {
    $cleanHtmlString .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $cleanHtmlString;
```

Output:

```html
<p>777</p>
<div>hello <b>world</b>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to write a similar solution but should I be concerned by the performance cost? If for example multiple HTML strings with a varied length are parsed will this be penalizing in a way or another?

Comment: I think that I will use this solution with a caching system

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `strip_tags` does not prevent XXS attacks, so from a security perspective I would not recommend it, see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

However, here is an example of the solution I suggested in the comments. The trick is to use a special character to escape your allowed tags. This makes for a straightforward solution, as you can just use `strip_tags`.

```
$string = '<b class="hello">Hello, </b><a>world!</a>';

$allowed = array(

    'b' => chr(1) . 'b_open',
    '/b' => chr(1) . 'b_close',
    'i' => chr(1) . 'i_open',
    '/i' => chr(1) . 'i_close',

);

// Remove your special character from the input to prevent it from being injected

$result = str_replace(chr(1), '', $string);

// Escape the valid tags

foreach ($allowed as $tag => $replacement) {

    $result = preg_replace('/<' . str_replace('/', '\\/', $tag) . '([^>]*?)>/i', $replacement, $result);

}

// Call strip_tags

$result = strip_tags($result);

// Replace back

foreach ($allowed as $tag => $replacement) {

    $result = str_replace($replacement, '<' . $tag . '>', $result);

}

echo($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications but in my opinion `strip_tags` doesn't prevent XSS attacks only if you use the second parameter as, like I stated in my question, it won't remove the attributes from the allowed list which is exactly the point of my question.
And sorry again but I don't really get the purpose of what you suggested. In addition to that, the code you provided doesn't handle HTML attributes. So what am I missing?

Comment: @KlaxCuy If the attribute functionality is important, I added that. But as was pointed out a regex may fail in some cases. This is a possible solution that specifically uses `strip_tags` with less complexity.